# which solution is better as performance in oracle?

Tags: performance, plsql, oracle11g

assume procedure `A` calculated 1000 number and wants the procedure `B` run for every one of this numbers and procedure `B` do some thing.
solution one : procedure `A` call procedure `B` 1000 times for numbers 
solution tow : procedure `A` save the numbers in a intermediate table then procedure `B` read the numbers
solution one cost is calling procedure `B` 1000 times and solution tow cost is inserting 1000 numbers (each number in a row) and reading(select) 1000 numbers.
i want to know which performance is better using plsql?

Comment: Basically, you are considering using a _queue_ instead of a direct call. Obviously, the former has extra overhead. But your example is underspecified: could A and B (and several instances of B) run in parallel ? How is the cost of generating numbers compared to B ? Does A and B have "wait states" that could be somehow exploited by running in parallel ? How should behave A and B in case of "failure" ?

Comment: several instances of B can not run in parallel and i did not understand the second part of your question.

Comment: For your 'intermediate table' are you thinking of using a normal table, a global temporary table, or a PL/SQL table (collection)? The overhead would be quite different for each.

Comment: i was thinking using a normal table

Comment: @jalalrasooly - that will be the most expensive option. I suggest you investigate [PL/SQL collections](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS005).

Comment: you mean using normal table make the second solution more expensive than the first solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example and given these as options, I would choose option two. Simply, we cant loop and call another procedure 1000 times rather a write and read is more efficient. In terms of maintenance, any failure in Procedure B will not warrant another run on procedure A and you can simply restart the second part.